# Can't type anything in xcode. Unknown plugin is installed

Tags: macos, xcode

I'm using Xcode on a system that belonged to a former employe and I can't type. There's a weird rectangle text cursor blinking and a blank line at the bottom that responds to my key strokes in a weird manner. If I press a key the text cursor will just get smaller. q will write the word RECORDING in the blank line. There's also the location path of the file I'm currently on, I'd also like that to be removed. I've wrote red numbers next to the problems I'm having.

[image]

Comment: I would just like to know? Is reinstalling a possibility? Also, this might be better asked in Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's not a possibility.

Comment: Alright. However this problem should be asked on Stack Overflow. People there would probably know more about this then the people here do.

Answer (score 1):

It's setup to use vim. There are a couple of plugins which do this in varying degrees. It's hard to say how to uninstall without knowing which plugin it may be.

It might be one of the following:

http://usevim.com/2012/11/28/vicious/

http://vimxcoder.com

https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim

http://www.corsofamily.net/jcorso/vi/

In case you need to use the vim bindings installed:

http://larc.ee.nthu.edu.tw/~cthuang/vim/files/vim-intro.html